# Tag rename request: "standards" => "community-guidelines"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Title says it all. So it's a "title-only question" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mark for bringing this up. Following up on our Slack discussion, I agree that it makes more sense for `standards` to be changed to `community-guidelines`.

I would be more than happy to go through this list and retag myself.  Or we can wait for Robert.

[image]

Comment: No need — done. It's generally better to do any mass retags through the moderator tools so all the edits don't *bump* every post to the top of the 'activity' page.